# Paired t test's statistic's numerator

Tags: t-test, paired-data

I am a bit confused about the numerator of the t-statistic in a paired t-test. I know it's the mean of the differences between the samples, but is it the mean of the *absolute* differences or mean of the signed differences? When I google'd this, the top few links seem to provide examples that suggest it's the mean of the signed difference, but that would make it the same as an unpaired t test.

I think it should be the absolute differences. e.g., suppose we have the following
$$
x_1 = [1, 2] \\
x_2 = [2, 1]
$$

Should the numerator be
$$
\frac{(1 - 2) + (2 - 1)}{2} = 0
$$

or
$$
\frac{\left|1 - 2 \right| + \left|2 - 1\right|}{2} = 1
$$

Comment: A paired and unpaired t-test test the same null hypothesis and therefore use the same numerator (the difference in means). Only the denominator (the standard error of the mean difference) differs between the two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the signed difference and that does not make it the same as the unpaired test.

Taking the absolute values is rarely going to be sensible (I can think of some cases, but not many). You are testing whether the difference is 0. You are interested in whether one is less than the other, on average, so you should not take the absolute value.  As a toy example consider paired data (say, on the right and left side of the body):

```
R:  10 20 20 10
L:  20 10 10 20
```

Clearly, R and L have the same mean. The usual paired t-test will show this, with t = 0 and p = 1.00.  If you take abs. value, then you will get that the difference is 10.

But it's not the same as the unpaired test, because the denominators are different and that makes the paired test more powerful. Also, using the unpaired test when the data are paired violates the assumption of independence.

Comment: wait, I'm a bit confused by "The paired test takes the differences first." so if you take the differences first, and then take the mean of the these differences (which I thought was the numerator), don't you get that the mean of the differences is zero, hence `t=0 => 0` for a paired t test too?

Comment: also, to clarify, I don't mean the paired and unpaired tests are identical. I just meant that the numerator of the t-statistic seems to be the same in a paired and unpaired t-stat, right? I understand the denominator (standard error) is different between the 2

Comment: I will modify my answer. I see how it's incorrect.